# How to get geo location details in baidu

Tags: javascript, php, baidu

We need geo location details from both google and baidu .But We get geo location details from google api,we referred following link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation. But baidu using we can't get the geo location details. Give the suggestion to get geo location details include lat,lng using baidu map api?

Example code:

```
var options = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
timeout: 5000,
maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
var crd = pos.coords;

console.log('Your current position is:');
console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
};

function error(err) {
console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: We will not just 'give you suggestions'... What have you tried? Where's your example code?

Comment: Example code added for. I thinks its referred google. But we want to implement geo location to baidu map.

Comment: Have you looked up any API or docs for Baidu? You haven't mentioned anything you've tried so far...

Comment: OKay, well that's a japanese site, so I don't think this question is going to go anywhere. Sorry, either come back when you have a more detailed problem, or I'd recommend removing it.

Comment: Check this url also
http://amazeui.github.io/docs/en/javascript/geolocation/

Comment: That URL has errors on it, and it does not show the map where it's supposed to, I'd look elsewhere.